# Using an array inside of a function to store names

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to practice javascript and I read a small challenge on a website about           making a small system where users can follow and unfollow one another. I am still new to     javascript and programming in general so please forgive my ignorance. Below is what i came up with. I am trying to make this off the top of my head because this might be the best way to learn a language imo.

Basically in this small function, I created an empty array set in a function. I then set     the function to the onClick  handler in the  tag. Is this a good way to store names or things in general? Am I on the right track to do this small task?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<input id="searchbox" value = "names">
<button type="radio" onClick="listOfPeople();">

<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";

function listOfPeople (){

var storedPeople = [];

listOfPeople();


};





</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where did you get "use strict"? And it looks like your listOfPeople method will cause a stack overflow because it calls itself.

Comment: This is an endless recursion without condition: `listOfPeople() { listOfPeople(); }`.

Comment: Explain a bit more of your project, it's a bit not enough to make an effective sample

Comment: You are on the right track with an array inside a function. Please read about [JS function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures) to understand where data is accessible and where not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've declared the storedPeople array inside the listOfPeople function, that will limit the "scope" from where you can add or remove items from it to the listOfPeople function.

Something like this would not work with your setup currently, because the storedPeople array is is in a "closure" because it was declared inside a function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function listOfPeople (){
    var storedPeople = [];
    listOfPeople();
};
alert(storedPeople[0]);
</script>
```

This should show how to declare the array outside of the function so it has a "wider scope", meaning that it can be accessed by more than just inside of the listOfPeople function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="searchbox" value = "names">
<button type="radio" onClick="listOfPeople();">

<script type="text/javascript">

    // declare the storedPeople array outside of the function
    var storedPeople = [];

    // modify the array in the function
    function listOfPeople (){
        storedPeople.push(document.getElementById("searchbox").value);
    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're properly calling your button.

But there's one problem within your javascript function : inside of 'listOfPeople' you're calling 'listOfPeople'.
You shouldn't do this because it will never stop calling the same function again and again. And then stack overflow : Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Your function should look like :

```
function listOfPeople (){
var storedPeople = [];
};
```

Otherwise it is a good start!

Answer (score 0):

you have not clearly mentioned what you need your given code to do.
like others mentioned, listofpeople() is recusrive but there's no condition to break it.
try to create your code in http://plnkr.co/ and explain what is it that you want as opposed to what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to do the search progressively as the user types you may use 'onchange' see the demo here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

as  a modification to Zack's code it would be

```
<body>

<input id="searchbox" value = "names" onchange="listOfPeople();">
<button type="radio" onClick="listOfPeople();">
```